# show file name instead of image icon in the editor

Tags: uiimage, xcode9

Ever since I updated to xCode 9, I've noticed that an array of images shows up in the editor as an extremely tiny render of the image, so small I can't even make it out. It also appears to be slowing Xcode down. How do I set it to show both the image and file name like it did before the update?

Thanks